# How is the a value of this in ember.js computed property defined?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to understand why using function() inside a computed property works, but a fat arrow does not.

Here is a class I created, and two definitions of computed properties, one passing in `function() {}` (foo) , and the other passing in `() => {}` bar.  I included both styles being passed into an array forEach() also for reference (foo1, and bar1).

Can someone explain what is going on in each of these four instances?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const Light = Ember.Object.extend({
    isOn: false,
    color: 'red',

    foo: Ember.computed( 'isOn', 'color',  function() {
      console.log(`this in foo is ${this}`);
    }) , 
    foo1: [1].forEach(function() {
      console.log(`this in foo1 is ${this}`);
    }) ,
    bar: Ember.computed( 'isOn', 'color',  () => {
      console.log(`this in bar is ${this}`);
    }), 
    bar1: [1].forEach( () => {
      console.log(`this in bar1 is ${this}`);
    }) 

});

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  appName: 'Ember Twiddle',

  init() {
    this._super();
    this.set('bulb', Light.create());
  }

});
```

here is the template that references the all 4 properties

```
<h1>Welcome to {{appName}}</h1>
<br>
<br>
{{outlet}}
<br>
<br>
<p> the bulb is {{bulb.isOn}} </p>
<p> the bulb is {{bulb.foo}} </p>
<p> the bulb is {{bulb.foo1}} </p>
<p> the bulb is {{bulb.bar}} </p>
<p> the bulb is {{bulb.bar1}} </p>
```

and here are the results printed to the console.

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
VM66 ember.debug.js:6395 DEBUG: Ember      : 2.4.4
VM66 ember.debug.js:6395 DEBUG: Ember Data : 2.4.3
VM66 ember.debug.js:6395 DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.11.3
VM66 ember.debug.js:6395 DEBUG: -------------------------------
VM70 about:srcdoc:29 this in foo1 is undefined
VM70 about:srcdoc:35 this in bar1 is undefined
VM70 about:srcdoc:26 this in foo is <(unknown mixin):ember360>
VM70 about:srcdoc:32 this in bar is undefined
```

Here is the link to the twiddle 
https://ember-twiddle.com/d5905b42eff57e8ad5c99a27a3199429?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C

Answer (score 3):

Your functions of the form

```
foo1: [1].forEach(function() {
  console.log(`this in foo1 is ${this}`);
```

are not computed functions, as you probably know; they are executed at parse time. The value returned by `forEach` is `undefined` Therefore, the value of the `foo1` property will be the constant `undefined`. The console log will happen exactly once, when the definition is parsed, before a `Light` object is even instantiated.

Your function

```
bar: Ember.computed( 'isOn', 'color',  () => {
  console.log(`this in bar is ${this}`);
}),
```

does not work because arrow functions have **lexical `this`** (in other words, the `this` of the surroundings). The `this` will be the `this` in effect at the time the definition is parsed, which is likely to be either `undefined` or `window`. Ember invokes the functions specified as part of computed properties in the context (with the `this`) of the object in question, so obviously having a `this` equal to `undefined` won't work at all.

Comment: I think I do understand why the others did not work.
I think what I am still a little hung up on is understanding why 'this' does not somehow end up being the context of Ember, since the function is passed into Ember.computed?

Comment: @nPn you are passing `function() {}.bind(this)` to `Ember.computed`, the context you are passing is either window or undefined(depending on strict mode), the Light ember object hasn't been created yet, take a look at the duplicate question. If it is still unclear find us in the -help or -general channels on the ember community slack.

Comment: I _think_ I get it now.  The key info being: "Ember invokes the functions specified as part of computed properties in the context (with the this) of the object in question".  I did look at the Ember.computed source and I saw an apply() in there so I guess that's how that is accomplished.  It is probably such a common practice (frameworks helping to get 'this' right for you), but for me (naive) I just could not understand _why_ it worked. Thanks for the pointer to the slack community.