# Using arrow functions as observers fails?

Tags: ember.js

It seem like I can't use arrow functions as observers, anonymous methods works fine. Am I missing something crucial, why does the context differ?

```
ember.debug.js:32096 TypeError: _this3.get is not a function
    at .sessionChanged (session.js:77)
    at Object.applyStr (ember.debug.js:23331)
    at Object.sendEvent (ember.debug.js:16842)
    at ObserverSet.flush (ember.debug.js:20171)
    at endPropertyChanges (ember.debug.js:20682)
    at Object.changeProperties (ember.debug.js:20707)
    at Object.setProperties [as default] (ember.debug.js:21786)
    at exports.default._emberMetalMixin.Mixin.create.setProperties (ember.debug.js:35465)
    at invalidate (session.js:98)
    at session.js:42
```

Anonymous function - Works.

```
  /**
   * Session event observer.
   */
  sessionChanged: Ember.observer('user', function() {
    // Get the user value
    const user = this.get('user');

    // Get the session token
    const token = this.get('token');

    console.log(user, token);
  }),
```

Observer method using arrow function - Throws exception.

```
  /**
   * Session event observer.
   */
  sessionChanged: Ember.observer('user', () => {
    // Get the user value
    const user = this.get('user');

    // Get the session token
    const token = this.get('token');

    console.log(user, token);
  }),
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36613693/how-is-the-a-value-of-this-in-ember-js-computed-property-defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrow functions is a ES6 feature which is transpiled in Ember.js using Babel.js.
Arrow functions is a shorter notation that also implicitly bind the current context to the defined function.

In your case, current context is undefined because definition takes place inside a module and the top level `this` in a module is undefined in Babel ES6. (see http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)

It works using anonymous functions because ember explicitly bind your object context to it. Thing it cannot do with arrow functions because Babel will do the binding automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.